# Set value to other columns in query

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi StackoverFlow Community,

I would like to achieve the following.

Current queried table

```
 m_id s_s                    s_e                 a_s_t      comm  cosk
    101  2019-12-23 13:08:49  2019-12-23 13:13:12   NS        dt2   p2
    101  2019-12-23 13:13:12  2019-12-23 13:14:35   UP        dt2   p2
    101  2019-12-23 13:14:35  2019-12-23 13:14:56   MS        dt4   p4
```

Desired queried table

```
 m_id s_s                    s_e                 a_s_t      comm  cosk
    101  2019-12-23 13:08:49  2019-12-23 13:13:12   NS        dt2   p2
    101  2019-12-23 13:13:12  2019-12-23 13:14:35   UP        UP    UP
    101  2019-12-23 13:14:35  2019-12-23 13:14:56   MS        dt4   P4
```

I wrote a query to get the first table(current queried table). What i would like to have is the following.

Set comm, cosk to up where a_s_t is up

Comment: That is a simple update query. Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple CASE Statement

```
CASE WHEN A_S_T = 'UP' THEN 'UP' ELSE COMM END AS COMM,
CASE WHEN A_S_T = 'UP' THEN 'UP' ELSE COSK END AS COSK
```

Comment: the comm and cosk are derived from another query like this: tbl1.comm, tbl1.cosk in tbl2 i select the values

Comment: The case when query, gives the same result as the previous query( no up value in comm or cosk

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the values in table itself then use UPDATE query

```
UPDATE tableName
SET [comm] = 'UP' ,  [cosk] = 'UP'
WHERE a_s_t = 'UP'
```

If you just want to select these values without changing the table then Use below Query:

```
SELECT   [m_id], [s_s],[s_e],[a_s_t],
        CASE WHEN [a_s_t] = 'UP' THEN 'UP', ELSE [comm] END AS [comm],
        CASE WHEN [a_s_t] = 'UP' THEN 'UP', ELSE [cosk]END AS [cosk] 
FROM tableName
```

Comment: the comm and cosk are derived from another query like this:

tbl1.comm, tbl1.cosk

in tbl2 i select the values

Comment: The case when query, gives the same result as the previous query( no up value in comm or cosk

Comment: It will be good if you can share the entire query with joins to other tables. It will help us to understand the reason why CASE is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case.. when` or `decode` as following:

```
-- using case when

SELECT m_id, s_s,s_e,a_s_t,
        CASE WHEN upper(a_s_t) = 'UP' THEN a_s_t ELSE comm END AS comm,
        CASE WHEN upper(a_s_t) = 'UP' THEN a_s_t ELSE cosk END AS cosk 
FROM (your_query);

-- or using decode

SELECT m_id, s_s,s_e,a_s_t,
       Decode(upper(a_s_t),'UP',a_s_t,comm) AS comm,
       Decode(upper(a_s_t),'UP',a_s_t,cosk) AS cosk 
    FROM (your_query);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks, for your comment, but the decode is not working.

The case when query, gives the same result as the previous query( no up value in comm or cosk

Comment: Then your up is not UP but up. Means case must be different. See updated answer now.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But its still the same result where comm and cosk is not up

Comment: **where comm and cosk is not up** obviously, It will not change anything for the record where comm and cosk is not up. What is your expectation then?